# Disable Cloudant's _user database and go back to Cloudant's own security feature

Tags: authentication, couchdb, cloudant

I once enabled the `_user` database in my cloudant account to try out some things (via the `HTTP PUT` call to `_security` `https://cloudant.com/for-developers/faq/auth/` last Paragraph), but now I would go back to the regular cloudant authentication. How can I make this happen?

Answer (score 3):

You can enable regular Cloudant authentication by removing the "nobody" roles from the _security object. The "nobody" roles essentially let anyone through Cloudant's auth layer, so CouchDB's can kick in.

To do this you need to PUT a JSON document like the following to the _security endpoint of the database (for example https://USERNAME.cloudant.com/DATABASE/_security):

```
{
  "cloudant": {
    "nobody": []
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I just got some feedback from the cloud ant IRC chat. 
To reset the authentication system to the cloudant system I had so 
PUT the following document to `security`

```
{
  "cloudant": {
    "nobody": []
  },
  "readers": {
    "names":[],
    "roles":[]
  }
}
```

Thanks to user mikerhodes